# Activating a new cell not working within Google Sheets onSelection(e) execution?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Is there some way to force the selection of another cell (e.g. A1) after someone has selected a different cell (e.g. B2)?  If i use a simple ...getRange(1,1).activate() code, it works when I hit "Run" in the script editor, but not when a selection is made in the real spreadsheet.  Please help?

I've basically written a long "onSelection" code that allows someone to mark their answers to a trivia game as "Correct" or "Wrong" by clicking on the corresponding cells.  (I do this with onSelection(e) because buttons don't work on mobile.)

However, if they get two answers correct in a row, onSelection(e) doesn't work because they've already selected "Correct" the first time.  I want the code to select 'A1' automatically so it's ready for their next Correct/Wrong input.

A code as simple as the following works when I select any cell in Google Sheets and then hit "Run" in the script editor, but it doesn't not work when I select a cell with my mouse.

```
function onSelectionChange(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  sheet.getRange(1,1).activate();
}
```

Comment: Try closing and reopening the spreadsheet.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61929649/simple-trigger-onselectionchangee-not-work

Comment: Unfortunately no dice...still doesn't work.  Interestingly, when I add   console.log('test')  immediately after the ..activate(); line, it never shows up in the log.  But I also don't get any errors.  It's like trying to use activate() stops the script, but without throwing an error.

Comment: No I copied your script and it wouldn’t run until I closed and reopened.